# Connecting MSP430 CC3000 to Xively

Tags: msp430, xively

I am looking to connect my TI MSP430+CC3000 eval kit to Xively for evaluation. There is a Xively C library that I would like to use. However, i wondering if anyone else has already done it who could share with me? As I saw there is already Xively feed with MSP430+CC3000 on-line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The TI wiki has had a [*"CosmCloudApp"*](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php?title=CosmCloudApp&oldid=135974) page for some time, but recently it's been deleted. The link here is to a previous revison of that page. Since there are quite a few public feeds when you search for ["CC3000"](https://xively.com/search?q=cc3000) it may be the case that TI have shipped this example at one point, but I was unable to find the source code or binary on [TI website](http://ti.com) and according to the [TI E2E forum](http://e2e.ti.com/search/default.aspx#q=cosmcloudapp) it's nowhere to be found for quite a while.

After having a quick look at the *SimpleLink API Reference Manual* ([download zip](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=swrc266a&fileType=zip)), I can see that it provides BSD-style socket API. Therefore it should be relatively easy to port [Xively C library](https://github.com/xively/libxively/) to CC3000 API using provided [POSIX communiction layer](http://xively.github.io/libxively/posix__comm_8c.html).

Comment: There might be something useful in this forum post referring to that page: http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/851/t/226056.aspx